most frequent *rolling* value on a object/str pandas dataframe column
I would like to have a new column with the most frequent rolling value from another str/object column.
          date     name state
0   2024-02-29    Alice    CA
1   2024-02-27      Bob    HI
2   2024-02-29    Cindy    ID
3   2024-02-25      Dan    MT
4   2024-02-29  Elliott    CA
..       ...        ...   ...

I am trying to get the most frequent rolling state (for each row).
I have tried different combinations (and subsets) of

.rolling()
.apply()
.mode()
mode() from different libraries
custom mode() function

which usually generates one of a handful of errors complaining that the column is non-numeric. I understand what the error is telling me - that it expects to aggregate and apply a numeric function (.mean() .sum() ...) - but its not even getting to the .apply() function...
def fail_now(x):
    raise Exception('wow! we made it here!')

>>> df['state'].rolling(window=25).apply(fail_now)
...
pandas.errors.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

>>> df[['state']].rolling(window=25).apply(fail_now)
...
pandas.errors.DataError: Cannot aggregate non-numeric type: object

>>> df[['state']].rolling(window=25)['state'].apply(fail_now)
...
pandas.errors.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

I also tried a multitude of different things, including the raw flag in .apply() with no luck

Please make a reproducible pandas example including desired output

User guide reference: "Windowing operations currently only support numeric data (integer and float) and will always return float64 values."

@wjandrea thank you! thats exactly what i was looking for... they should not bury this significant information so deep... thank you!!!

but what is not reproducible about it? im trying to learn...

out of curiosity, what would you expect rolling on a string field to behave like?

i'd expect it to behave the same way it does for numerical data --- provide rolling window size data on which you apply some function and return a value

rolling only works with numeric values, you could first factorize your data (to have numbers), then map the original names:
a, idx = pd.factorize(df['state'])

df['rolling_mode'] = (pd.Series(a, index=df.index)
                        .rolling(3, min_periods=1)    # window=3 for the demo
                        .apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
                        .map(dict(enumerate(idx)))
                     )

Output:
         date     name state rolling_mode
0  2024-02-29    Alice    CA           CA
1  2024-02-27      Bob    HI           CA
2  2024-02-29    Cindy    ID           CA
3  2024-02-25      Dan    MT           HI
4  2024-02-29  Elliott    CA           CA


thank you @mozway!!!
twas hoping an expert like yourself would provide a fancy alternative  after learning that rolling is for numerical only... THANK YOU!!!
